# Calling specific Value in PHP Array

Tags: php

sorry for asking , if someone already asked . Here my question : 
I have this function :

```
function view_jurusan($uid){
        $sql="select jurusan_detil.jurusan_tarif
            from jurusan 
            inner join jurusan_detil
            on jurusan.jurusan_uid=jurusan_detil.jurusan_uid
            where jurusan_detil.jurusan_uid='".$uid."'
            ORDER by jurusan_detil.jurusan_kolom  ASC
            ";
        $sqlcek=mysqli_query(connection(),$sql);
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlcek)){
            $data[]=$row;
        }
        return $data;   
    }
```

at other php page

```
$view=view_jurusan($uid);
```

Then i tried print_r($view). and have this result

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [jurusan_tarif] => 11 ) [1] => Array ( [jurusan_tarif] => 12 ) [2] => Array ( [jurusan_tarif] => 13 ) [3] => Array ( [jurusan_tarif] => 14 ) [4] => Array ( [jurusan_tarif] => 15 ) [5] => Array ( [jurusan_tarif] => 21 ) [6] => Array ( [jurusan_tarif] => 22 ) [7] => Array ( [jurusan_tarif] => 23 ) [8] => Array ( [jurusan_tarif] => 24 ) [9] => Array ( [jurusan_tarif] => 31 ) [10] => Array ( [jurusan_tarif] => 32 ) [11] => Array ( [jurusan_tarif] => 33 ) [12] => Array ( [jurusan_tarif] => 41 ) [13] => Array ( [jurusan_tarif] => 42 ) [14] => Array ( [jurusan_tarif] => 51 ) )
```

How to call/echo [jurusan_tarif] => 11 only at php? i already tried  `echo $view['jurusan_tarif'][0];` not works . Sorry for poor english . Thank you

Comment: It shoud be `echo $view[0]['jurusan_tarif']`, it will print out `11`

Comment: yes , thats works like charm, catcon. Thank you !!

Comment: how to close this post anyway ? the problem is solved already .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try as below.

```
echo $view[0]['jurusan_tarif'];
```